# Recursive reference of a dataframe column to the row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following program wherein, I created a multi-index dataframe with three columns and eventually populated one column with a nested list of tuple of lists. I the flattened the indexes and tried to iterate over the rows `ix, rec = next(df.iterrows())`.
I then de-referenced data column `rec.data` from the iterated row (`rec`), and found out it was a memory object `<memory at 0x000000000D6E0AC8>`. On calling the obj attributed on the record `rec.data.obj`, I realised it is an array with the content of the entire row. To get to the actual content, I have to fetch the item index which is quite non-intuitive.

```
>>> print(rec.data.obj[2])
[(['9', '"', 'X', '12', '"'], 0.9993008259451988)]
```

**Sample Recreatable Example**

```
def foo():
    return [(['9', '"', 'X', '12', '"'], 0.99930082594519876)]
import pandas as pd

def spam():
    index = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []],
                          labels=[[], []],
                          names=[u'timestamp', u'key'])
    columns = ['data', 'col1', 'col2']
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
    for ix in range(4):
        key = ('XXX', ix)
        df.loc[key, 'data'] = str(foo())
        df.loc[key, 'col1'] = "col1_{}".format(ix)
        df.loc[key, 'col2'] = "col2_{}".format(ix)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True) 
    return df

def bar():
    df = spam()
    ix, rec = next(df.iterrows())
    print(rec.data)
    print(rec.data.obj)
    print(rec.data.obj[2])

bar()
```

**Output**

```
<memory at 0x000000000D6E0AC8>
['XXX' 0 '[([\'9\', \'"\', \'X\', \'12\', \'"\'], 0.9993008259451988)]'
 'col1_0' 'col2_0']
[(['9', '"', 'X', '12', '"'], 0.9993008259451988)]
```

I am clueless and cannot understand, what am I missing

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
def bar():
    df = spam()
    rec = next(df.itertuples())
    print (rec)
    print (rec.data)
bar()
Pandas(Index=0, timestamp='XXX',
       key=0, 
       data='[([\'9\', \'"\', \'X\', \'12\', \'"\'], 0.9993008259451988)]',
       col1='col1_0', 
       col2='col2_0')

[(['9', '"', 'X', '12', '"'], 0.9993008259451988)]
```

Comment: Thank you. The reason I was using `iterrows`, as I wanted to avoid called enumerate, over `itertuples`. In any case, any idea why my code was failing?

Comment: Not, I am have idea. Maybe for iterator is possible use `print (rec.Index)`